# Windows install missing drivers

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

When trying to install Windows on a PC with Windows already installed (for other reasons I need to do a complete reinstall) using a USB bootable drive from the official ISO, I get errors about missing media drivers. Is this a known issue or do I actually need those drivers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you should not get any error if you are using official ISO and completely re-installing windows. Probably, you should explain error in detail, or may be try to clean current windows first and then reinstall windows from bootable usb/ISO.

Answer (score 0):

> I get errors about missing media drivers. Is this a known issue or do
> I actually need those drivers?

I don't think it is an "issue".   Windows 10 (via the Microsoft Catalogue (of drivers)) will install all the drivers it can.

Allow Windows 10 to install.

Then determine what drivers you still need and get them from the manufacturer's support website.

Ideally the manufacturer will have a Driver Update App. Get that and scan for all driver updates.

What you are seeing is (to my way of thinking and in my experience) can be normal for some machines.

Answer (score -1):

With a quick google search it seems the most likely reason is corrupt installer media. So I'd start by re-downloading the iso and re-creating the installer.

Sources:

https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/resolving-a-media-driver-is-missing-error-during-windows-10-clean-install/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-a-media-driver-your-computer-needs-is-missing-or-a-required-cd-dvd-drive-device-driver-is-missing-error-message-when-you-install-windows-ad4bec88-167e-eeeb-15ab-ccd6982bd859

For future reference... it's easier to suggest fixes if you give a bit more basic info, such as Windows version. For example Win 10 advice might not be appropriate for Win 7 installation.